# How to Perform Column-Wise Logical Operations in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, logical-operators

I'm working with an Excel sheet of customers, a snippet of which looks like this:

| Name | Month | Contacted? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | January | Yes |
| Sally | January | Yes |
| Smith | January | No |
| Alice | March | No |
| Peter | May | Yes |

I'm trying to get a count of the customers in each month that have been contacted and those in each month that haven't been contacted.  I've been able to get a count of the number of customers in each month by doing `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B5="January")` and a count of how many customers have been contacted with `=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C5="Yes")`.  It feels like there should be a way to perform column-wise logical operation, like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(AND(B2:B5="January", C2:C5="Yes"))` to get a count of the number of customers that were contacted in January, but that doesn't work.

The end table that I'm trying to generate would look like this, where any edits to the above table should update this one:

| Month | Total Customers | Contacted Customers | Non-Contacted Customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| March | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| May | 1 | 1 | 0 |

What's the right way to implement these formulas?

Comment: Easier to use `COUNTIFS` in my opinion: `=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,"January",C2:C5,"Yes")` . But if you want to use `SUMPRODUCT`, use `*` for `AND` logic: `=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5="January")*(C2:C5="Yes"))`.

Comment: An alternative approach is to use a pivot table

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Where your Data is in Column A to C and your Table Starts at Column E